# Will ubuntu work for a windows surface 2

Tags: compatibility, microsoft, surface, arm

I'm new to Linux and want to install Ubuntu on my surface 2 all I want to know is. Is this possible? Please can I have an answer from someone who has done this so I know it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible, but since you are new to Linux, it is very unlikely that you could get it to work satisfactorily. Surface 2 is an ARM system that requires a signed bootloader. To install Ubuntu, you would have to jailbreak the Surface 2, then build your own ARM image of Ubuntu (Ubuntu does not ship images for ARM hardware) and then install it. And then you will have to deal with the numerous driver incompatibilities you will run into.

The Surface Pro, on the other hand, is an x86 tablet, and the boot loader isn't locked down, so an install is a much easier prospect. See [Linux users rejoice, here’s Ubuntu on the Surface Pro 3](http://www.geek.com/microsoft/linux-users-rejoice-heres-ubuntu-on-the-surface-pro-3-1594864/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about a surface 2 (which is an Arm system using a Tegra processor from Nvidia) the answer is no. Even if you jail broke the system I do not believe that Ubuntu has UEFI keys for the Arm processors.

If you are talking about the Surface 2 Pro which is an Intel processor then, yes you can run Ubuntu on it and there are numerous how-to articles on the web. Just search using the term "Surface 2 Pro Ubuntu".